# Getting "fugitive: No Gbrowse handler found"

Tags: plugin-fugitive

When I run `:Gbrowse` from vim-fugitive, I get

```
fugitive: No Gbrowse handler found for 'https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli'
```

Can it just spool that out to `xdg-open`?

Comment: You probably need Rhubarb for github compatibility.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: I hit this issue and finally realized I hadn't actually run :PlugInstall (using vim-plug) to install vim-rhubarb. With that installed, it's working for me.

Answer (score 6):

The issue seems to be solved by installing https://github.com/tpope/vim-rhubarb.